# How to avoid inherited members using autosummary and custom templates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc

I generate a python documentation using `sphinx.ext.autosummary`. The `autodoc` and `autosummary` is configured as follow in conf.py :

```
autodoc_member_order = 'bysource'
## Default flags used by autodoc directives
autodoc_default_flags = ['members','undoc-members']
## Generate autodoc stubs with summaries from code
autosummary_generate = True
```

I use a template :

```
myModuleName
=======

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :template: modules.rst

   myModule
```

Modules template is :

```
{{ fullname }}
{{ underline }}

.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}

   {% block functions %}
   {% if functions %}
   .. rubric:: Functions

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: {{ objname }}
   {% for item in functions %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block classes %}
   {% if classes %}
   .. rubric:: Classes

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: {{ objname }}
      :template: class.rst
   {% for item in classes %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block exceptions %}
   {% if exceptions %}
   .. rubric:: Exceptions

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in exceptions %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```

And class template is :

```
{{ fullname }}
{{ underline }}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}

   {% block methods %}

   {% if methods %}
   .. rubric:: Methods

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: {{ objname }}
   {% for item in methods %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block attributes %}
   {% if attributes %}
   .. rubric:: Attributes

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: {{ objname }}
   {% for item in attributes %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```

It works fine but this adds every method inherited in the documentation while the flag 'show-inheritance' (which is supposed to add every inherited member) is absent.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think some kind of patch to autosummary is needed. There was a similar problem with imported members some time ago (https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2336).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The patch has been merged in december 2016, it will certainly be available in the next release of sphinx.

Comment: The patch I linked to was for problems with **imported** members (available in Sphinx 1.6.1; see http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/changes.html#release-1-6-1-released-may-16-2017). Your issue with **inherited** members needs another patch which does not exist yet AFAIK.

Answer (score 7):

it seems indeed that none of the flags (e.g. `:no-inherited-members:`) have any effect on this, but you could just modify your class template to solve the problem.

```
{% for item in methods %}
{%- if item not in inherited_members %}
    ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
{%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

the above seems to do the trick for me.
hope it helps...